# Stored procedure to loop through a list of tables deleting data in batches of 100000 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 schemas with exactly the same tables `schema_oltp` and `schema_olap`. I want to delete from selected tables in `schema_oltp` only the data which already exists in `schema_olap`. The tables I want to delete from are listed in a table called `archived_to_delete`. For each of the tables listed in `archived_to_delete`, I need to delete the data in batches of 100 000. This is what I have so far. It only deletes 100 000 in each table and stops. I want it to continue until there is no data in `schema_oltp` which also exists in `schema_olap`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `schema_oltp`.`schemaDeletes`(IN       from_schema VARCHAR(100), IN to_schema VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN   


DECLARE v_tname varchar(100);
DECLARE v_pkey varchar(455);
DECLARE v_upfield varchar(455);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_limit INT DEFAULT 100000;
DECLARE v_deleted INT;


DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
    INNER JOIN archived_to_delete b
    ON a.table_name = b.table_name
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_oltp'
    AND COLUMN_KEY='PRI'
ORDER BY b.archived_to_delete_id;




DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


OPEN table_cursor;

REPEAT

FETCH table_cursor INTO v_tname, v_pkey;

IF NOT done THEN



    SET v_deleted=0;
      SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',from_schema,'.', v_tname, '  WHERE ',v_pkey,' IN (SELECT ', v_pkey, ' FROM ',to_schema,'.', v_tname, ')  limit ',v_limit,';');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET v_deleted=v_deleted+1;
IF v_deleted = v_limit THEN
commit;
SET v_deleted=0;
END IF;


    SELECT CONCAT('Deleting...',v_tname);

 END IF;

 UNTIL done END REPEAT;
 CLOSE table_cursor;



    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```